# trouble with image insert into html via JS

Tags: javascript, html

Having trouble getting my script to show in pycharm or when I cast to the chosen browser. I followed the instructor's video, but I guess Im missing something. Can someone review my code and see if you can find what I am missing? Im suppose to insert the image to pare up the movie with the correct info, but cant get it to work.
Thank you for nay help.

//UPDATE//
I did get the image to function and show up now, misplaced one of these " " ". Though still having trouble calling the image in the js file so i can have it organized properly. Is there a better way of doing this, perhaps using it in html as part of the body or another way?

///UPDATE 2///
So im having trouble matching up specific images to the "movies" and not sure what the best method should be for this. IS there a way to create sections in the .js file and call individual piece and put images between them or can i insert images in the .js file its self between the sections?

```js
//Movie 1
var movie_1={
    name: "Princess Mononoke",
    genre: "Fantasy/Adventure",
    year: "1997",
    actor: "Billy Crudup as Ashitaka",
    actress: "Claire Danes as San"
};

//image things
//function addTheImage() {
//    var img = document.createElement("img");
//    img.src = "img/Princess_Mononoke_Japanese_poster.png";
//    var src = document.getElementById("x");
//    src.appendChild(img);
//}

//function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
//    var img = document.createElement("img");
//    img.src = "img/Princess_Mononoke_Japanese_poster.png";
//    img.width = 200;
//    img.height = 300;
//    img.alt = alt;

    // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
//    document.body.appendChild(img);
//}

// document.write(<img src="Module_10/img/Princess_Mononoke_Japanese_poster.png">)

//screen stuff
document.write("<b><font size = 6>");
document.write("The movie's title is " + movie_1.name);
document.write("</b></font size>");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<br>");


//Genre
document.write("<font size = 4>");
document.write("The movie's genre is mostly " + movie_1.genre);
document.write("</font size>");
document.write("<br><br>");

//Actors
document.write("<font size = 4>");
document.write("The two main cast members consists of " + movie_1.actor + " and " + movie_1.actress);
document.write("</font size>")
document.write("<br>")
document.getElementById("x")
document.write("<br><br><br>")



////Movie 2////
var movie_2={
    name: "Attack The Block",
    genre: "Sci-fi/Action",
    year: "2011",
    actor: "John Boyega as Moses",
    actress: "Jodie Whittaker as Sam"
};

//image things
//function addTheImage() {
//    var img = document.createElement("img");
//    img.src = "img/attack_block.jpg";
//    var src = document.getElementById("x");
//    src.appendChild(img);
//}

//function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
//    var img = document.createElement("img");
//    img.src = "img/attack_block.jpg";
//    img.width = 200;
//    img.height = 300;
//    img.alt = alt;

    // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
//    document.body.appendChild(img);
//}

// document.write(<img src="Module_10/img/attack_block.jpg">)


//screen stuff
document.write("<b><font size = 6>");
document.write("The movie's title is " + movie_2.name);
document.write("</b></font size>");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<br>");


//Genre
document.write("<font size = 4>");
document.write("The movie's genre is mostly " + movie_2.genre);
document.write("</font size>");
document.write("<br><br>");

//Actors
document.write("<font size = 4>");
document.write("The two main cast members consists of " + movie_2.actor + " and " + movie_2.actress);
document.write("</font size>")
document.write("<br>")
document.getElementById("x")
document.write("<br><br><br>")


////Movie 3////
var movie_3={
    name: "The Old Guard",
    genre: "Action/Fantasy",
    year: "2020",
    actor: "Chaarlize Theron as Andy",
    actress: "Harry Melling as Steven Merrick"
};

//image things
//function addTheImage() {
//    var img = document.createElement("img");
//    img.src = "img/attack_block.jpg";
//    var src = document.getElementById("x");
//    src.appendChild(img);
//}

//function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
//    var img = document.createElement("img");
//    img.src = "img/attack_block.jpg";
//    img.width = 200;
//    img.height = 300;
//    img.alt = alt;

    // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
//    document.body.appendChild(img);
//}

// document.write(<img src="Module_10/img/attack_block.jpg">)


//screen stuff
document.write("<b><font size = 6>");
document.write("The movie's title is " + movie_3.name);
document.write("</b></font size>");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<br>");


//Genre
document.write("<font size = 4>");
document.write("The movie's genre is mostly " + movie_3.genre);
document.write("</font size>");
document.write("<br><br>");

//Actors
document.write("<font size = 4>");
document.write("The two main cast members consists of " + movie_3.actor + " and " + movie_3.actress);
document.write("</font size>")
document.write("<br>")
document.getElementById("x")
document.write("<br><br><br>")




//image things
//function addTheImage() {
//    var img = document.createElement("img");
//    img.src = "img/Princess_Mononoke_Japanese_poster.png";
//    var src = document.getElementById("x");
//    src.appendChild(img);
//}

//function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
//    var img = document.createElement("img");
//    img.src = "img/Princess_Mononoke_Japanese_poster.png";
//    img.width = 200;
//    img.height = 300;
//    img.alt = alt;

    // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
//    document.body.appendChild(img);
//}


////MotoGp QATAR////
//The things
var motogp_1 = new Pilot("Bastianini ","Enea",24,"Ducati",25,"Losail Circuit, QATAR Grand Prix");
var motogp_2 = new Pilot("Binder","Brad", 26,"KTM",20,"Losail Circuit, QATAR Grand Prix");
var motogp_3 = new Pilot("Espargaro","Pol", 30,"Honda",16,"Losail Circuit, QATAR Grand Prix");

//Functions and things for MotoGP
function Pilot(first,last,age,team,points,track){
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastname = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.team = team;
    this.finalpoints = points;
    this.trackname = track;
}

////To screen
document.write("<b><font size = 6>");
document.write("MotoGP QATAR Race Results for 3/28/2021");
document.write("</b></font size>");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<br>");

document.write("<font size = 4>");

document.write(motogp_1.firstName + " " + motogp_1.lastname + ": "+ motogp_1.team +", "+ motogp_1.finalpoints +" at "+ motogp_1.trackname);
document.write("<br><br>");
document.write(motogp_2.firstName + " " + motogp_2.lastname + ": "+ motogp_2.team +", "+ motogp_2.finalpoints +" at "+ motogp_2.trackname);
document.write("<br><br>");
document.write(motogp_3.firstName + " " + motogp_3.lastname + ": "+ motogp_3.team +", "+ motogp_3.finalpoints +" at "+ motogp_3.trackname);
document.write("<br><br>");
document.write("</font size>");


////MotoGp Indonesia////
//The things
var indo_1 = new Pilot("Oliveria ","M",24,"KTM",25,"Mandalika International Street Circuit");
var indo_2 = new Pilot("Quartararo","F", 26,"Yamaha",20,"Mandalika International Street Circuit");
var indo_3 = new Pilot("Zarco","J", 30,"Ducati",16,"Mandalika International Street Circuit");

//Functions and things for MotoGP
function Pilot(first,last,age,team,points,track){
    this.firstName = first;
    this.lastname = last;
    this.age = age;
    this.team = team;
    this.finalpoints = points;
    this.trackname = track;
}

////To screen
document.write("<b><font size = 6>");
document.write("MotoGP Indonesia Race Results for 3/28/2021");
document.write("</b></font size>");
document.write("<br>");
document.write("<br>");

document.write("<font size = 4>");

document.write(indo_1.firstName + " " + indo_1.lastname + ": "+ indo_1.team +", "+ indo_1.finalpoints +" at "+ indo_1.trackname);
document.write("<br><br>");
document.write(indo_2.firstName + " " + indo_2.lastname + ": "+ indo_2.team +", "+ indo_2.finalpoints +" at "+ indo_2.trackname);
document.write("<br><br>");
document.write(indo_3.firstName + " " + indo_3.lastname + ": "+ indo_3.team +", "+ indo_3.finalpoints +" at "+ indo_3.trackname);
document.write("<br><br>");
document.write("</font size>");
```

```html
<html>
    <title>Objects</title>
    <head>
        <script src="JS/image_test.js"></script>
        <script src="JS/movies.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<!--        <img src="img/Princess_Mononoke_Japanese_poster.png" hegiht="300" widht="200">-->
<!--    <div id="header"></div>-->


</script>

    </body>

    <head>
         <script src="JS/moto.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your img src is a " between img/ and Princess... Remove that and it should work

Comment: That seemed to work thank you. I have another issue I found as well. Ill update to continue what im running into. Thanks again.